# Orbeon and Liferay - shared user

Tags: liferay, orbeon

I'm trying to make application which is build on Liferay with OrbeonForms. I have a question: Is there some oportunity to share user with both? I mean I want to set default language in Orbeon which is the same as in logged user in Liferay e.g. Liferay user uses Japanese language, and he open orbeon via his Liferay portal, and there should be also Japanese language set as default.

regards

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible right now but I entered an RFE as it makes sense:

https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/1122

Comment: So if there is no oportunity to create shared user, maybe it is possible to get liferay userId from my own persistance layer ? I want to get userId, because my goal is to save to database id of user who create form (after click on save in formBuilder). Regards

Comment: The Liferay user should be propagated as the `Orbeon-Username` header to the persistence layer.